# dbgsym archive for libGL

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, debug-symbols

I am running Ubuntu LTS on a x64 system with an nVidia GPU.

When doing perf profiling runs, I like to have as many symbols available. In Ubuntu, this comes down to installing the [dbgsym](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace) companion packages.

E.g. the package **libglx-mesa0:amd64** has the companion **libglx-mesa0-dbgsym:amd64** to provide the symbols.

But my perf profile runs do not show any OpenGL functions.

Where can I find the debug symbols for the package **libnvidia-gl-430-dbgsym:amd64** so that my GL calls show up symbolicated, and not as hexadecimal numbers?

```
Samples: 8K of event 'cpu-cycles:pp', Event count (approx.): 7344996076
  Children      Self  Command        Shared Object               Symbol                                                      ◆
+   92.45%     0.00%  Train          [unknown]                   [k] 0xffffffffffffffff                                      ▒
+   91.19%     0.00%  Train          Train                       [.] main                                                    ▒
+   91.15%     0.00%  Train          Train                       [.] Vis::Update                                             ▒
+   90.61%     0.00%  Train          Train                       [.] Vis::Draw                                               ▒
+   88.13%     0.00%  Train          libnvidia-glcore.so.430.09  [.] 0x0000000000a1795d                                      ▒
+   88.01%     0.00%  Train          Train                       [.] Vis::DofFinishReadDepth                                 ▒
-   88.01%     0.00%  Train          Train                       [.] finish_pbo_read                                         ▒
     finish_pbo_read                                                                                                         ▒
     0xa1795d                                                                                                                ▒
     0xa16b2f                                                                                                                ▒
     0xe1adea                                                                                                                ▒
   + 0xe1ad06
```

Or do I have to switch to my Intel GPU for that, with an Open Sourced libGL library?

I am running **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS** with this GL:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1650/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 430.09
```

Comment: "Where can I find the debug symbols for the package libnvidia-gl-430-dbgsym:amd64 so that my GL calls show up symbolicated, and not as hexadecimal numbers?" At nvidia's private company computers. The driver is proprietary, they do not provide any public debug symbols.